# Adding Atom (editor) to the path in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, bash, git, path

I have downloaded the Atom (editor)'s `.zip` file to my Windows 7 computer and haven't installed it using the installer.

When I try to launch Atom from the Git BASH terminal in a casual directory, I cannot. When I try to find it in the 'Add or Remove Programs' section in the Control Panel, it is not present.

Nonetheless, I am able to go to the path where the program is and run it from that folder.

I think this is due to the path not being specified, so how can I add the path of Atom on the Windows 7 system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deal with the `shell` as a normal bash shell (until you can).

- In general from inside a bash shell you should **add** the full directory to your $PATH variable

  ```
  PATH=$PATH:/your/app/path
  ```

  You can add this line to one of the files automatically executed when you launch a shell, e.g. `.bashrc` or  `.bash_profile`.
- An alternative way to execute the program is to create an `alias` and to put it in one of the starting files... e.g.

  ```
  alias  Atom='/my/full/path/to/AliasExecutable'
  ```

  **This approach should be preferred**, if the program does not need to find other sub-command in the path. Remember that each time you misstype a command the system has to search for each executable in each of the directories present in the path. So one directory with few files is rarely a problem. Few directories with thousends of executable files or many un-needed directories in the path, will cause waste of (seeking) time and resources (memory allocated), and cause more security hazards (malicious software in the directories in the path...).
  You may find interesting to read [here](https://coderwall.com/p/_-ypzq/git-bash-fixing-it-with-alias-and-functions)

---

#### Tl;dr

Note the similarity with the usual windows 7 solutions...

- From [inside your windows DOS-like shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23400088/3569208)

  ```
  Set PATH=%PATH%;(your new path);
  ```

  Note that here the separator is `;` under Linux is `:`.
- From your [desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41859486/3569208) for the DOS-like shell

  > Click on the Start menu, search for "environment," click "Edit environment variables for your account."

  > In the window that opens, select "PATH" under "User variables for username" and click the "Edit..." button. Add your new path to the end of the existing Path, separated by a semi-colon (%PATH%;C:\Python27;...;C:\NewPath). Click OK on all the windows, open a new CMD window, and test the new variable.

  You should have a similar procedure to set up the git-bash environment variable too...

Comment: adding path using the command prompt will overwrite the whole path or will it only add that to the system environment path?

Comment: Note that `PATH=$PATH:/my/newly/added/path` and `PATH=:/my/newly/added/path:$PATH` behave differently: the first adds to the (old) path the new directory. The second rewrite the path variable starting from the new directory and adding the old path. If you have two executables with the same name, it will be executed the first fond, following the order of the directories in the path.

Comment: Thank you for the information that solved the problem. :)

Comment: You're welcome... BTW I suggest you to try first the `alias` way... and be curious.